# Payment Gateway integration with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment, mastercard

I am new to ReactJS and implementing payment of bills in my application for which I need to implement the payment gateway services from mastercard. The application should support both AMEX and MASTERCARD payments. As a reference, we need to use the following link

https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedSession/integrationModelHostedSession.html

But how I will use the same code in the mentioned link in the reactjs app is a confusion. Because in the render() method I was unable to use the script and the callbacks. Is there different way to implement in reactjs.

I also did a bit of google and came across

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mastercard-hosted-session

But my confusion is when I click the Pay button how to put everything in perspective with the link above.

If anyone has a better approach or solution, kindly let me know

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: Hi,

have you completed this? I am also stuck on implementing this. Kindly help me on this

Comment: Yes, I have done it, Let me know where are you stuck

Comment: I am using hosted session and I lost control over inputs. I wanna to validate fields before sending/submitting. How can I achieve that?

Comment: in hosted session, your fields are validated in the hosted sessions Payment configure method

Check this website

https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedSession/integrationModelHostedSession.html

Comment: Hi @user1295308 That I know, but I want to validate first then send it to session.js via configure

Comment: since it is a hosted session so I believe the validation and control is with the master card also once you load them, it will open the respective iframe for those input fields. Can you share what you have done so that we can have a look

Comment: Hi @user1295308 I somehow amange to do validation.  Have you implemented 3ds verification also? If yes could you show me how to achieve that?